# How to transform bounded pcollection to unbounded in Python with Apache Beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to transform a few Terabytes of mail logs stored in GCS without using too much memory.

As recommended in the [guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements), I'm adding timestamp to each element, split it to a sliding window and I have specified an (aggregation) trigger before sending it to a `GroupByKey` and a `ParDo` parser after. This should do, but still `GroupByKey` waits for all data to arrive. **Why?**

I have tried it with Direct and Google Dataflow runner as well.

What do I miss?

Here's the gist of the code:

```python
    known_args, pipeline_options = parse_args(sys.argv)
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    lines = pipeline | 'read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input)
    parsed_json = lines \
      | 'cut' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x[39:])\
      | 'jsonify' >> beam.Map(json_loads).with_outputs('invalid_input', main='main')

    keyed_lines = parsed_json['main']\
      | 'key_filter' >> beam.Filter(lambda x: u'key' in x)\
      | 'keyer' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['key'], x))\
      | 'log_processed_rows' >> beam.Map(log_processed_rows)

    window_trigger = trigger.DefaultTrigger()

    windowed_lines = keyed_lines\
       | 'timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestampDoFn())\
       | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.SlidingWindows(size=3600+600, period=3600), trigger=window_trigger, 
                                     accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING) # 1 hour steps with 10 minutes of overlap

    results = windowed_lines \
        | 'groupbykey' >> beam.GroupByKey()\
        | 'parse' >> beam.ParDo(ParseSendingsDoFn()).with_outputs('too_few_rows', 'invalid_rows', 'missing_recipients', main='main_valid')  

    output = results['main_valid'] \
        | 'format' >> beam.Map(output_format)\
        | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output, file_name_suffix=".gz")
```

Comment: Now I've did, but causes error. Great tip though! I wished it was that easy.

Comment: Hmm can't see anything, did you manage to get it working? If you did then posting the answer would be super helpful. I am wondering if it is a `bounded` pipeline or did you pass `--streaming`, whether the `DefaultTrigger` is causing it to wait till completion, or maybe WriteToText can't flush until completion

Comment: @Andor - any update? I am in a similar situation and cannot seem to get the window to triggger

Comment: I have not used Beam/DF since then. Spark and plain Python suited better in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The [default trigger](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#provided-windowing-functions) requires the entire data set to be available before processing that is why it waits for all data to arrive.

Try using a [Data-driven](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#data-driven-triggers) triggers or a [Processing time triggers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#processing-time-triggers).

Furthermore, the [SlidingWindows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#provided-windowing-functions) is mostly used for running averages and since you are only adding a timestamp the single global window might be a better option.

**EDIT**

Regarding the windowing, you can can have a streaming job that creates a [pcollection from in-memory](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#creating-a-pcollection) data and have a side input from the GCS storage.

Comment: As I wrote, the whole mess is necessary because of the ammount of data to process. Processing time trigger would really make it unpredictable. Data driven triggers were not available for Python at that time. 
Anyways, since then I've been to Crunch conf, where one of the authors of Beam claimed that this could not be made. It's because that each source has an internal property, if it's streamed or not. If it's not streamed, then you can't really use windowing.